# Combinatorial problem about all natural divisors being a perfect square

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

Let $P_k(n)$ be the product of all natural divisors of n, which are divisible by k. (Empty product is 1)

Prove that $P_1(n)...P_n(n)$ is a perfect square.

I checked small cases, they are all right? Stuck on the general case.

Comment: You checked some small cases, did you think about them?  If $n=2, P_1(2)=2, P_2(2)=2,$ the product is $4$.  What happens for other primes?  Now try $6$, as the smallest product of two different primes.  What happens with $4$, which is the square of a prime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $d$ be a divisor of $n$, how many times does it appear in the product? it appears in $p_k(n)$ if and only if $k$ divides $d$. hence $d$ appears as many times as the number of divisors it has.

So if we calculate $p_1(n)p_2(n)\dots P_k(n)$ by first putting together all the same divisors into blocks each divisor $d$ is going to appear as many times as the number of divisors $d$ has.

Notice a number has an odd number of divisor if and only if it is a square. Therefore if $d$ is not a square it appears an even number of times and hence the product of the elements of the block of $d$ is a square. Notice if $d$ is a square the same happens because the block is a product of squares.

Hence all the blocks are squares. Hence the total product is a square.